# convert php project to django project

Tags: php, django, django-models

I am working in a software firm in which there is a requirement to convert already existing php project to django project My question  Can I maintain the database of php project to django project so that I can maintain my old data 
Please help me

Comment: Please add more details.  What are you currently using for your database?  MySQL?

Comment: Does a question like this belong on SO? It doesn't read like an explicit programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You may start reading the django docs here:

- [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/legacy-databases/).